# Why the Gemmorah's disputes are left unresolved?

Tags: halacha-theory, talmud-bavli, machlokes

In the Gemmorah we can see three types of the Halachic resolution of a dispute:

1. the issue is settled and the Halachah is clearly ruled
2. multiple approaches mentioned but there's no clear resolution
3. two approaches are mentioned and the Gemmorah announces Tekku (no way of resolution)

The following Poskim (Geonim, Rishonim inc. Rambam, Abchronim) had to choose either side in those disputes (#2 and #3) to Pasken the Halachah.

Why didn't the editors of the Gemmorah Pasken all the disputes themselves, and left so many disputes unresolved?

Comment: Re #2 - what sort of cases did you have in mind? Any machlokes Abaye and Rava is already resolved - we pasken Rava except יע״ל קג״ם. Any machlokes Rav and Shmuel is already resolved - רב באיסורי ושמואל בדיני. Etc. What machlokos does the Gemara leave unresolved without a תיקו?

Comment: I read a very good analogy once. Imagine a child is disturbing class and the teachers are meeting to decide whether to expel him. Half the teachers say he should be expelled because he disturbs the other students. The other half say to keep him in because he would go off the derech otherwise. What is the right answer? It depends.... of the child, context, specifics, etc. The gemara leaves both options possible, and the rav facing the specific *shaila* will rule based on the specifics. Not saying it applies everywhere but it makes *eilu v'eilu divrei Elokim hayim* tangible

Comment: How are the editors supposed to Pasken the disputes if the Gemarah couldn't?

Comment: @DonielF I thought about this and I think you misunderstand those rules. They were issued by the Geonim, generations AFTER the Gemmorah was written. In the times of the Gemmorah, it was left unresolved, as I stated. You might use this argument about just any Machlokes - didn't B'Shammay know that the Halachah is according to B'Hilel? No, in their times there was no resolution, it came generations later.

Comment: @AlBerko Where do you get that from? As far as I’m aware, things like יע״ל קג״ם were included by Ravina and Rav Ashi - later than Rava and Abaye, sure, but they were the editors of the Gemara, not the Geonim. To me it seems that, at least regarding #2, the editors of the Gemara *did* pasken all the disputes themselves.

Comment: @mbloch Let me continue your line of reasoning - let's leave all the disputes דברי א"ח? Why did they excommunicate R"E - Let it hang, and the later generations will decide?

Comment: @DonielF You add nothing to the discussion. That was the reason I didn't bring examples, not to argue about each one separately. The fact is that they could either resolve them all as they wish or to leave all the Machlokos open. But they acted *seemingly* arbitrary. What might be a reason for that behavior?

Comment: @AlBerko Again, I’m not seeing any instances in which #2-type cases were left unresolved. That’s all I’m asking for - you say that regarding #2-type cases they had to choose either side, can you provide even one such case? Or should you narrow your question to focus in on #3-type cases? I didn’t think it was such a difficult request.

Comment: @DonielF The easiest way is to check for example Kesef Mishne on Rambam, where he says that Rambam Pasak as one of the Rabbis, e.g.: *"שכיר הבא לישבע אין מחמירין עליו וכו'. כתב ה''ה מימרא שם וכו' ופירוש רבינו לפי הנראה כך הוא וכו' **ופסק כרב חסדא**."* Meaning there's no resolution in the Gemmora and Rambam could Pasken either of them. https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Hiring.8.9?lang=bi

Comment: Consider Maggid Mishnah to Sechirus 3:10 who felt the need to tell us that the Rambam paskened like Rava - yet we always pasken like Rava. They’re just telling you which opinion he paskened like, not that they had to make that decision because the Gemara didn’t.